# detect unsubscribe from email body which doesn't have list-unsubscribe header

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, google-api-nodejs-client, list-unsubscribe

To provide **unsubscribe** functionality, am getting the (mailto, subject) / (link) fields from the "List-Unsubscriber" header. But some emails does not have this header, instead they provide the link in email body. But gmail is able to get the link and implement this functionality. The catch is: i tried to send a mail with UnSubscribe link in the body and gmail ignores it. So should i regex the text of email to implement the unsubscribe functionality or ignore and implement only the emails with 'List-Unsubscribe' header?

Comment: If you can regex the text and it covers at least some cases, why not?

Comment: in some real time use cases, user might provide the unsubscribe text and link for other purposes. In such cases, don't you think it is inappropriate to process and provide that link in the ui?